# Exclude syntax in this code

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I would like to exclude 2 files here:

```
Source: {tmp}\*; DestDir: {tmp}; Excludes: uninstall.dll, uninstall.vsf; Flags: deleteafterinstall
```

The syntax is right, or I should specify them like this?:

```
Source: {tmp}\*; DestDir: {tmp}; Excludes: {tmp}\uninstall.dll, {tmp}\uninstall.vsf; Flags: deleteafterinstall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Excludes`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=Excludes) parameter directory tree base is specified by the [`Source`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=Source) parameter path. All patterns listed there are relative to this dir tree base path. From what you posted is hard to tell what's correct for you because those script excerpts do something different. Your first script sample excludes this:

> ```
> ┌───────────────────────────┐
> │ Script                    │
> │   └ {tmp}                 │
> │       ├ File.ext          │
> │       ├ uninstall.dll     │
> │       └ uninstall.vsf     │
> └───────────────────────────┘
> ```

Whilst the second script sample would exclude (if you'd have specified [`recursesubdirs`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm#recursesubdirs) flag) from the `{tmp}` subfolder relative to the `{tmp}` source folder this:

> ```
> ┌───────────────────────────┐
> │ Script                    │
> │   └ {tmp}                 │
> │       ├ File.ext          │
> │       └ {tmp}             │
> │           ├ uninstall.dll │
> │           └ uninstall.vsf │
> └───────────────────────────┘
> ```